# No mapping found for HTTP request URI[js & css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans

I know this question have been ask many times but i still can't anything to solve my problem. I get this error when i try to access from index.jsp to all.jsp. I find it weird that my index.jsp able to load all those resources(css & js) but when i access all.jsp I'm unable to load all my resources.

My Explorer path

[project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBW13.png)

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

all.jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/tether/tether.min.css">
```

Error message

```
Warning:   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/smartcoursesystem/university/assets/tether/tether.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

UPDATE :

I just found out that the problem is if there is two RequestMapping in a controller I'm not able to access to the resources(css & js).My HomeController only one RequestMapping whereas my universityController using two RequestMapping.Still, I don't have a solution. Any solution? Please help...thanks

HomeController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/home")
public class homeController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCount(Model m){

    universityModel model1 = new universityModel();
    courseModel model2 = new courseModel();
    m.addAttribute("countUniv", model1.countUniv());
    m.addAttribute("countCrs", model2.countCrs());

    return "index";
}

}
```

universityController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/university")
public class universityController {

public static String entity_name = "University";

@RequestMapping(value="/all", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAll(Model m){

    universityModel model = new universityModel();
    m.addAttribute("univList", model.getAll());
    m.addAttribute("entity", entity_name);
    m.addAttribute("count", model.countUniv());

    return "all";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer solved by replacing

```
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>
```

to

```
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/university/assets/**"/>
```

but now I'm facing a problem...my welcome-file is not working because i use

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

By replacing "/" to

```
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
```

help to solve the problem. However, if my url-pattern change to "*.htm", I will not able to access my resource again for all.jsp...please help..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/assets/tether/tether.min.css'/>">
```

make sure you have taglib declaration in your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```